# convert output to list(and nested dictionary)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto

```
import boto.ec2

sgs = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1').get_all_security_groups()

for sg in sgs:
    for rule in sg.rules:
        print sg, sg.id, "inbound:", rule, " source:", rule.grants

SecurityGroup:default sg-e1304484 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(80-80)  source: [67.184.225.222/32]
SecurityGroup:default sg-e1304484 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(5500-5500)  source: [67.184.225.222/32]
SecurityGroup:Pub_HDP_SG sg-e632d982 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(80-80)  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
SecurityGroup:sg3-MySecurityGroup-LB0QF9UQAOEF sg-4fe73728 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(22-22)  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
SecurityGroup:sg3-MySecurityGroup-LB0QF9UQAOEF sg-4fe73728 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(80-80)  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
SecurityGroup:RDP Rule - open everyone  sg-42d58d27 inbound: IPPermissions:-1(None-None)  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
SecurityGroup:us-east-open-all sg-97ffa7f2 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(22-22)  source: [10.0.20.100/32]
SecurityGroup:us-east-open-all sg-97ffa7f2 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(53-53)  source: [10.0.20.100/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: IPPermissions:-1(None-None)  source: [sg-e632d982-995635159130]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(22-22)  source: [67.184.225.222/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(1024-65535)  source: [10.0.20.100/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(80-80)  source: [24.12.30.198/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: IPPermissions:udp(138-138)  source: [10.0.20.100/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: IPPermissions:udp(53-53)  source: [24.12.30.198/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(30015-30015)  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: IPPermissions:icmp(-1--1)  source: [10.0.20.100/32]
SecurityGroup:default sg-c65a20a3 inbound: IPPermissions:-1(None-None)  source: [sg-c65a20a3-995635159130]
SecurityGroup:default sg-c65a20a3 inbound: IPPermissions:-1(None-None)  source: [sg-99c4befc-995635159130]
SecurityGroup:sg3-MySecurityGroup2-1HGPN4UF57XN6 sg-4ee73729 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(22-22)  source: [192.168.1.12/32]
SecurityGroup:AWS-AMI-SG sg-35568d51 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(22-22)  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
SecurityGroup:launch-wizard-2 sg-932255f6 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(22-22)  source: [10.0.20.100/32]
SecurityGroup:launch-wizard-2 sg-932255f6 inbound: IPPermissions:tcp(443-443)  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
>>>
```

Hello all,

For Each SecurityGroup, how can i convert that into a List that in turn will have a dictionary of the cidr block, protocol type and the port...so from output above, the SecurityGroup called "default" had 2 rules...allowing TCP port from 80 and 5500 to the source IP and then SecurityGroup called "Pub_HDP_SG" had only one rule...so on and so forth....here is the output that i am trying to get out in the form of a list....

what I am planning to do is, take the list(and nested dictionary) and pass that to a function that will in turn spitout a cloudformation template using troposphere (something like "http://imil.net/wp/2015/06/04/rock-your-cloudformation-with-troposphere-and-boto/")

```
rule1 = [{
    'cidr': '67.184.225.222/32',
    'proto': 'tcp',
    'port': 80
},{
    'cidr': '67.184.225.222/32',
    'proto': 'tcp',
    'port': 5500
}]

rule2 = [{
    'cidr': '[0.0.0.0/0',
    'proto': 'tcp',
    'port': 80
}]

rule3 = [{
    'cidr': '0.0.0.0/0',
    'proto': 'tcp',
    'port': 22
},{
    'cidr': '0.0.0.0/0',
    'proto': 'tcp',
    'port': 80
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_all_security_groups()` returns you  a list of objects. And each object contains other object, so you need to understand the heiracrvhy first. Then once you got this you can iterate through the result and construct a dictionary.

For example:

```
[
  {
     'cidr': x.rules[0].grants[0], 
     'proto': x.rules[0].ip_protocol
     # so on ....
  } for x in sgs if x.rules
]
```